# Set newly loaded rows to be selected by default in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am lazy loading the ag-grid with data from the server when the scroll reaches the end of the table. Using the headercheckbox I am able to select all the rows in the current block. But when i lazy load the next set of data, i require it to selected by default too. How can this be achieved?

This is my current code :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes['assayDataList']){
      this.updateRowData();
      this.rowCountOnRowUpdate = this.rowData.length;
      this.gridOptions.suppressScrollOnNewData = this.rowData.length <= 10 ? false : true;
      if(this.isSelectAll == true){
        this.gridApi.forEachNode(function(rowNode,index){
          //rowNode.setSelected(true);
          this.gridApi.selectNode(rowNode);
        })
      }
    }
  }

  public updateRowData(){
    var self = this;

    if(this.assayTableData == undefined){
      this.assayTableData = this.assayDataList;
    }
    else{
      this.assayTableData = this.assayTableData.concat(this.assayDataList);
    }
    if(this.assayDataList.length<self.gridOptions.cacheBlockSize ||this.assayDataList.length==0 ){
      self.stopApiCalls = true;
    }
    else{
      self.stopApiCalls = false;
    }
    this.rowData = this.assayTableData;

  };
```